# What is this built-in Apple app with a target-shaped icon?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

On the Apple Watch, what is this built-in app with a target-shaped icon?
Launching it crashes instantly.

[image]

Comment: That's an app that either didn't install correctly, is in the process of being installed, or (if you're an app developer) an app without a Watch icon.

Comment: Any idea how I can remove it?

Comment: Find an app that didn't install properly or was a failed install. You'll probably have to delete that app and restart both devices.